# including Boost to a VS2008express crashes intellisense

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost

I use Visual Studio 2008 Express.
When I include boost headers to my project (Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories) intellisense stops working (even for std::).

When I delete boost from Additional Include Directorie everything goeas back to normal.

Any ideas?

kind regards

Comment: Should work.. What path exactly you include and which boost number?

Comment: C:\stan\soft\windows_deps\boost_1_55_0

Comment: Does it work with Alt+<Right Arrow>? And are there any messages in status string?

Comment: Seems that it can be Express issue - missing some component(s) from the full version.

Comment: There is a message: IntelliSense: 'No additional information available'. Alt+<Right Arrow> works the same

Comment: Just checked on my friends computer: intellisense crashes also in non-express version, when you include boost folder (and #include <boost/asio.hpp>)